# Универсальный класс для создания HTML элементов

Tags: javascript, html, классы

Определил Класс. Объявил в нем метод, в котором создаю элемент и добавляю ему нужные css-классы. Вопрос как сделать так, чтобы в метод или Класс передать неопределенное количество css-классов.

```
class Element {
    constructor(elem, className) {
      this.elem = elem
      this.className = className
    }
    createItem() {
      const element = document.createElement(this.elem)
      element.classList.add(this.className, "xxx", "yyy")
      return element
    }
   }

   const form = new Form('form', 'form-style', 'form-style2', 'form-style3', ...)
   document.body.append(form.createItem());
```

Нужно, чтобы в инстанс Класса передавалось неопределенное количество css-классов

Comment: Не надо пытаться изобретать велосипед, класс для HTML элементов уже существует и его можно использовать, чтобы создать [пользовательские элементы](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заменить текущий код:

```
constructor(elem, className) {
  this.elem = elem
  this.className = className
}
```

на этот:

```
constructor(elem, ...classNames) {
  this.elem = elem
  this.classNames = classNames
}
```

а в строке

```
element.classList.add(this.className, "xxx", "yyy")
```

писать

```
element.classList.add(...this.classNames, "xxx", "yyy")
```

---

в итоге в конструкторе будет применяться **[rest оператор](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Rest_parameters)**, а в добавлении классов - **[spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)**

Comment: Да, все получилось! Благодарю.